# Concatenation the string values in python

Tags: python, variables, azure-devops, global-variables, string-substitution

I am trying to concatenation the string values like below in the python

args = parser.parse_args()

regionCode = args.regionCode

azure_api_token = args.azure_api_token

computerName  = args.computerName

targetOu = 'OU=XXX,OU=$regionCode,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX'

in the regioncode I am fetching the value from the build parameters I am trying to assign it in the target OU $regioncode but the value is not fetching or substituting

can someone please help me with the command how to substitute the variable value into the target OU

Comment: You can substitute variables in string using f-strings.

```targetOu = f"OU=XXX,OU={regionCode},OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX"```

https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To substitute a variable in a string in python you can do in many different ways.

Here you can do:

*python 2:*

```
targetOu = 'OU=XXX,OU={},OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX'.format(regionCode)
```

*python 3:*

```
targetOu = f'OU=XXX,OU={regionCode},OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX'
```

There are many other ways to do so. But this has been answered in so many different threads that I won't bother writing other solutions.